# Different Policies for "Resource" routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, acl, policies

I have a system where Admin can manage doctors and doctor has ability to manage itself. For this, I am using [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization) using policies. I registered a policy for admins that it can access doctors like:

```
Route::resource('doctors', 'DoctorsController')->middleware('can:access-doctors, App\Doctor');
```

But what I need is a separate policy for just one route out of resource group i.e. `doctors.edit` so a doctor can edit own profile like: `can:edit-doctor, $doctor` something.

Is there a possibility to do this in a proper way or I have to make manual routes and assign policies rather than using resource routes???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you'll need a different endpoint to specify specific middlewares for each route.

You could do:

```
Route::get('doctors/{doctor}/edit', 'DoctorsController@edit')
    ->middleware('can:edit-doctor', 'App\Doctor'));

Route::put('doctors/{doctor}', 'DoctorsController@update')
    ->middleware('can:edit-doctor', 'App\Doctor'));

Route::resource('doctors', 'DoctorsController')
    ->except(['edit', 'update'])
    ->middleware('can:access-doctors, App\Doctor'));
```